# simple check tcp,port stopped doing anything

Tags: zabbix

I have one monitored host with one active item to check a cvs pserver on port 2401. Every minute the "last check" date updates and the "last value" stays "Down (0)", but in reality the server does not try to establish a tcp connection with the remote port. I can tell that by running `tcpdump "host $pserverhost"`.

The problem is that it was working in the past. I don't know what happened. `icmpping` simple check still works on that host.

OS: RHEL 6.8, zabbix-server-mysql 1.8.22-1.el6 from epel.

Here's how I configured the check after a fresh install:

```
Configuration / Templates / Template_Standalone / items / Create item
    cvs (pserver)
    simple check
    tcp,2401
    numeric unsigned
    decimal
    interval: 60
    store val: as is

Configuration / Templates / Template_Standalone: triggers / Create trigger
    CVS pserver on {HOSTNAME}
    {Template_Standalone:tcp,2401.last(0)}#1
    severity: average


Configuration / Hosts / Create Host
    linked templates: Template_Standalone
    ip: the ip
    dns: the dns name


Configuration / Hosts / Items
    disable all except CVS and ping


Configuration / Actions / Create Action
    test action
    event source: triggers
    Action operations / New
        Send message
        to: single user: Admin


Administration / Media types / Create Media Type
    Description: Email from zabbix
    type: email
    server: webmail.acme.com
    helo: acme.com
    email: zabbix@dioptase.acme.com


Administration / Users / Admin / Media / Add
    type: Email from zabbix
    Send to: basin@acme.com
```

Comment: Zabbix 1.8 is terribly old. Have you tried restarting Zabbix server? Are you monitoring by IP of DNS? If by DNS, does it resolve?

Comment: @Richlv It was selinux. After reboot it went back to enforcing and in zabbix log I saw `TCP expect network error: *** Cannot connect to [[1.2.3.4]:2401]: [13] Permission denied`